# How to download bytes of file from URL at specific location from in inputstream?

Tags: java, inputstream

How to download bytes of file from URL at specific location from in input-stream?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by location from an input-stream?

Comment: Assume my file size is of 10 Bytes. I created input stream for that then I want to read last 3 bytes from input stream. (8 to 10 bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to "read" all the bytes.  Just skip the first ones that you don't need.  When you get to the point that you want to start saving data from the stream, save just the bytes you want and then close the stream.

Depending on the class there are methods like `skip()` than can help you skip past the bytes you don't want.

Comment: if my file size is of 1GB and I want only last 1KB then It is west of my resources if I read all bytes...

Comment: OK. Can you tell me how to get file size?

Comment: Possibly the getContentLength() method on the URLConnection object.

Answer (score 1):

create input stream from URL, read bytes and do what you want with them, e.g.

```
InutStream in = new URL("http://foo.bar").openStream();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/usr/foo/bar");
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int n = 0;

while((n = in.read(buf))) {
    out.write(buf, 0, n);
    out.flush();
}

in.close();
out.close();
```